# Lambda Query "ROW_NUMBER OVER Partition" Like Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, lambda, ef-core-5.0

I have this Lambda

```
Tasks
    // Join Task Assignments and Join User Assigned to the Assignment (There are multiple Assignments per Task, i need the latest assignment)
    .GroupJoin(
        // Ordered them as i need the latest assigned
        TaskAssignments.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateAssigned)
            // Join the User who it was assigned to
            .Join(Users, ta => ta.UserId, u => u.Id, (ta, u) => new { ta.TaskId, Date = ta.DateAssigned, Name = $"{u.GivenNames} {u.Surname}", u.Email, u.Phone })
        , a => a.Id, a => a.TaskId, (t, a) => new { Task = t, Assignmnets = a })
    .SelectMany(o => o.Assignmnets.DefaultIfEmpty(), (l, r) => new { l.Task, Assignment = r })
```

Which generates this:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[EncodedId], [t0].[OrgId], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[ContactId], [t0].[PriorityId], [t0].[LocationId], [t0].[AssetId], [t0].[JobNumber], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Description], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactPhone], [t0].[Status], [t0].[GpsLongitude], [t0].[GpsLatitude], [t0].[RefCode], [t0].[CustOn], [t0].[TaskType], [t0].[LinkProcessed], [t0].[LinkProcessedDate], [t0].[ReadTask], [t0].[ReadDate], [t0].[RequestedDate], [t0].[DueDate], [t0].[CompletedDate], [t0].[LastUpdatedDate], [t0].[SubStatusId], [t0].[SubStatus], [t0].[QuoteEstimatorId], [t0].[QuoteTotalInc], [t0].[QuoteTotalTax], [t0].[QuoteTotalEx], [t0].[TotalMaterial], [t0].[TotalLabour], [t0].[TotalExpense], [t0].[TotalHours], [t0].[Deleted], [t0].[Inserted], [t0].[Updated], [t3].[test], [t3].[TaskId], [t3].[DateAssigned] AS [Date], [t3].[GivenNames] AS [arg0], [t3].[Surname] AS [arg1], [t3].[Email], [t3].[Phone]
FROM [Tasks] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[TaskId], [t1].[DateAssigned], [t2].[GivenNames], [t2].[Surname], [t2].[Email], [t2].[Phone]
    FROM [TaskAssignments] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [Users] AS [t2] ON [t1].[UserId] = [t2].[Id]
    ) AS [t3] ON [t0].[Id] = [t3].[TaskId]
ORDER BY [t3].[DateAssigned] DESC
```

The trouble i get is that there can be multiple assignments per Task i only need the most recent i know in SQL i can do this:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[EncodedId], [t0].[OrgId], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[ContactId], [t0].[PriorityId], [t0].[LocationId], [t0].[AssetId], [t0].[JobNumber], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Description], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactPhone], [t0].[Status], [t0].[GpsLongitude], [t0].[GpsLatitude], [t0].[RefCode], [t0].[CustOn], [t0].[TaskType], [t0].[LinkProcessed], [t0].[LinkProcessedDate], [t0].[ReadTask], [t0].[ReadDate], [t0].[RequestedDate], [t0].[DueDate], [t0].[CompletedDate], [t0].[LastUpdatedDate], [t0].[SubStatusId], [t0].[SubStatus], [t0].[QuoteEstimatorId], [t0].[QuoteTotalInc], [t0].[QuoteTotalTax], [t0].[QuoteTotalEx], [t0].[TotalMaterial], [t0].[TotalLabour], [t0].[TotalExpense], [t0].[TotalHours], [t0].[Deleted], [t0].[Inserted], [t0].[Updated], [t3].[test], [t3].[TaskId], [t3].[DateAssigned] AS [Date], [t3].[GivenNames] AS [arg0], [t3].[Surname] AS [arg1], [t3].[Email], [t3].[Phone]
FROM [Tasks] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[TaskId], [t1].[DateAssigned], [t2].[GivenNames], [t2].[Surname], [t2].[Email], [t2].[Phone],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TaskId] ORDER BY [DateAssigned]) AS RN
    FROM [TaskAssignments] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [Users] AS [t2] ON [t1].[UserId] = [t2].[Id]
    ) AS [t3] ON [t0].[Id] = [t3].[TaskId]  AND [t3].[RN] = 1
ORDER BY [t3].[DateAssigned] DESC
```

I'm struggling to get the same result in Lambda.

I have tried:

```
    Tasks
    // Join Task Assignments and Join User Assigned to the Assignment (There are multiple  Assignments per Task, i need the latest assignment)
    .GroupJoin(
        // Ordered them as i need the latest assigned
        TaskAssignments.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateAssigned)
            // Join the User who it was assigned to
            .Join(Users, ta => ta.UserId, u => u.Id, (ta, u) => new { ta.TaskId, Date = ta.DateAssigned, Name = $"{u.GivenNames} {u.Surname}", u.Email, u.Phone })
        , a => a.Id, a => a.TaskId, (t, a) => new { Task = t, Assignmnets = a })
    .SelectMany((o, i) => o.Assignmnets.DefaultIfEmpty(), (l, r, i) => new { l.Task, Assignment = r, Index = i })
```

But i get this error
 `CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Queryable.SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>>>, Expression<Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: the `result selector` does not accept 3 arguments (no argument for index). `(l, r) => new { l.Task, Assignment = r }` should work. If you want to include the index, you must include it in the `collection selector`, like `.SelectMany((o, i) => o.Assignmnets.DefaultIfEmpty().Select((e,k) => new { e, k }), (l, r) => new { l.Task, Assignment = r.e, Index = r.k })`. However I'm not so sure that such complicated query is supported and able to be translated to sql. Just give it a try, otherwise you may be stuck by its limitation.

Comment: @KingKing, thank you. Unfortunatelythat didn't work, new error: `NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'SelectMany'.`

Answer (score 0):

After @KingKongs comment and trying so many different variations, i just couldn't get it to work, so instead i removed that `.GroupJoin` and in the final `.Select` i queried the Assignments separately:

```
.Select(o => new TaskGridLine
{
    // Other Properties Removed.

    Assignments = _context.TaskAssignments
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.DateAssigned)
        .Join(_context.Users, ta => ta.UserId, u => u.Id, (ta, u) => new TaskAssignmentGridLine
        {
            TaskId = ta.TaskId,
            Date = ta.DateAssigned,
            Name = $"{u.GivenNames} {u.Surname}",
            Email = u.Email,
            Phone = u.Phone
        })
        .Where(x => x.TaskId == o.Task.Id)
        .ToList()
})
```

Performance seems to be a bit slower, but it's the outcome i needed and can live with 0.5 seconds wait time :P

Comment: this query is basically an inner join, it cannot do better, if it's slow, there maybe something related to your data size or datatable scheme.... Actually if you design your models to include a `one-many` relationship between `TaskAssignment` and `User`, you can just project for the result by using `navigation reference property`, e.g: `_context.TaskAssignments.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateAssigned).Select(e => new TaskAssignmentGridLine { TaskId = e.TaskId, ..., Email = e.User.Email, Phone = e.User.Phone }).Where(x => x.TaskId == o.Task.Id).ToList()`